# TRIAC not turning off correctly

Tags: triac, dimmer

I am using this circuit with a BTA16 TRIAC:

[image: Circuit]

The load is a 110/12 V transformer. I am getting spikes in the output.

[image: Spikes]

Note: CH1 is the secondary of the transformer (load), CH2 is the MOC3021 input.

How can I get rid of the spikes?

Comment: why don't you put the triac on the secondary side of the transformer .... you could use a moc3020 or similar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your TRIAC **does** turn off correctly. Remember, it's turning off automatically as soon the **current** through it is zero. Not as soon the voltage over it is zero.

What you have there is a slightly inductive load which introduces a phase-shift between voltage and current. It's all okay. Those spikes will become a bit smaller as soon you put more load on the 12V side of the transformer, but in general, they do no harm. They only affect your minimal control angle.